# Upload binary data from react-native to AWS S3 using PUT presigned URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, fetch

I want to upload a file to AWS S3 [using a pre-signed url](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html).

I tried to send the file using form-data, but i got the following response with status 403 :

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
>   provided. Check your key and signing method.

After further investigation, i found that [AWS S3 does not support form-data](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/558#issuecomment-89385027) and suggests to use binary instead.

How should i do that in react-native?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out you can send the file in multiple ways, including `base64` and as a `Buffer`.

Using [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) and [buffer](https://github.com/feross/buffer):

Uploading as base64 worked, but i couldn't view the image. So i uploaded using a buffer:

```
export const uploadToAws = async (signedRequest, file) => {
  const base64 = await fs.readFile(file.uri, 'base64')
  const buffer = Buffer.from(base64, 'base64')
  return fetch(signedRequest, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg; charset=utf-8',
    'x-amz-acl': 'public-read',
   },
    body: buffer,
  })
}
```

Note that on the server, you need to make sure you are setting the correct Content-Type: `{ ContentType: "image/jpeg; charset=utf-8", 'x-amz-acl': 'public-read' }` as it seems fetch adds the charset to Content-Type.

Comment: in react native 0.64, fetch throws "network request failed"